# Not receiving response from facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, fbrequest-form

I have a problem when I send a post to my wall from my iPhone app.
I have all the delegate methods implemented and the method:

```
 -(void)request:(FBRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    // Keep this just for testing purposes.
    NSLog(@"received response");
}
```

My app works, the post appears on my wall, but my app doesn't get any response and stucks at my activity indicator. **Nothing appears in the console from NSLog.**

Does any one know, where's the problem? I'm dying here :-/

**EDIT:**

```
- (IBAction)fbButtonPressed:(id)sender {

// Create the parameters dictionary that will keep the data that will be posted.
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"330334280387192", @"app_id",
                               nil];

// Publish.
[self.facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

}

**I'm using the feed dialog for user input**

Comment: Show the piece of code where you POST to Facebook.

Comment: Didn't you forget to assign <FBRequestDelegate> protocol to your class?

Comment: @dmirkitanov no I didn't

Comment: @perigo what dmirkitanov said.